# Passing in a link into HTML as a variable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to pass in the link into the following code as a variable.

```
paste0(course$Students, "<br>", tags$a(href="x", "Click here!"))
```

Here, I pass in the number of students for the particular datapoint in *courses* (located in *course$Students*); however, each datapoint also has a specific link associated with it under *course$Link*.

How do I tell Shiny to put *course$Link* in lieu of x, i.e. make the choice of link dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You could use uiOutput/renderUI to make a dynamic UI in Shiny.

Here is an example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("chooseLink", "Link Address", choices = c("Amazon", "Google")),
  uiOutput("hyperlink")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$hyperlink <- renderUI({
    if (input$chooseLink == "Amazon"){
      link <- "https://www.amazon.com/"
    }else if(input$chooseLink == "Google"){
      link <- "https://www.google.com/"
    }

    tags$a(href = link, paste("To", input$chooseLink))

  })

}
```

The way you make it dynamically choose what the link might change in your case (I'm not familiar with the format of your data, so I can't say exactly how you would do it), but the point is still the same and it will allow you to have dynamic elements in your UI.